# How can I unpack an Ubuntu image?

Tags: ubuntu-core

We usually create/pack Ubuntu images with:

```
ubuntu-image -c beta --extra-snaps XXXXX --extra-snaps XXXX -o XXX.model
```

Now how can we unpack the generated Ubuntu image? Is there any tool to do that?